# libnfc - Emulate NDEF URI - NFC

Tags: c, nfc, ndef, acr122, lib-nfc

I am using an ACR122U-A9 NFC Reader and Mac OS X.
I want to emulate and NDEF URI Message (for example `https://stackoverflow.com`), so when an Android or (newer) iPhone approaches the NFC Reader, the Browser should automatically open the URI.

For that I am using the [nfc-emulate-forum-tag2.c](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/blob/master/examples/nfc-emulate-forum-tag2.c) example from `libnfc`, which is working. I can start the script and when i approch my Phone with an opened NFC App I am receiving a Tag.
In the nfc-emulate-forum-tag2.c example there is following script which sets the NDEF Message:

```
static uint8_t __nfcforum_tag2_memory_area[] = {
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // Block 0
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF,  // Block 2 (Static lock bytes: CC area and data area are read-only locked)
  0xE1, 0x10, 0x06, 0x0F,  // Block 3 (CC - NFC-Forum Tag Type 2 version 1.0, Data area (from block 4 to the end) is 48 bytes, Read-only mode)

  0x03, 33,   0xd1, 0x02,  // Block 4 (NDEF)
  0x1c, 0x53, 0x70, 0x91,
  0x01, 0x09, 0x54, 0x02,
  0x65, 0x6e, 0x4c, 0x69,

  0x62, 0x6e, 0x66, 0x63,
  0x51, 0x01, 0x0b, 0x55,
  0x03, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x62,
  0x6e, 0x66, 0x63, 0x2e,

  0x6f, 0x72, 0x67, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
}
```

- So how do I need to set this `__nfcforum_tag2_memory_area` for getting a NDEF URI Message for `https://stackoverflow.com`?
- Is there any c-library or script out there which i could use?